# Unable to resolve module from ; React native

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I recently ejected my react native expo app, and i'm trying to launch it on my ios simulator.
but i get this error when i do react-native run-ios.the code was working fine using expo and there was no error:
[image]

Here is my RdvScreen.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,Button,StyleSheet,} from 'react-native'
import { ProgressSteps, ProgressStep } from 'react-native-progress-steps';

import Recap from './RécapitulatifScreen';
import MyComponent from '../Components/RadioButton';
import Identification from './IdentificationScreen';
class RDV extends React.Component {

    render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <ProgressSteps>
            <ProgressStep label="Identification " nextBtnText="Suivant" >

                    <Identification />

            </ProgressStep>
        <ProgressStep label=" Motif" nextBtnText="Suivant" previousBtnText="Précédent" >
                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <MyComponent/>
                </View>
        </ProgressStep>
        <ProgressStep label="Récapitulatif" nextBtnText="Suivant" previousBtnText="Précédent" >
            <Recap/>
        </ProgressStep>
        <ProgressStep label="Confirmation" previousBtnText="Précédent" finishBtnText='Confirmer' onSubmit={()=> alert("Félicitation, votre rendez-vous est confirmé !")} >
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Confirmez votre rendez-vous</Text>
            </View>
        </ProgressStep>
    </ProgressSteps>
    </View>

    );
  }

}
```

and this is my project path:
[image]

i'll appreciate your help

Comment: can you show RécapitulatifScreen.js ..  did you export RécapitulatifScreen correctly?

Comment: @AnwarGul yes here is the code :

Comment: import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,Button,StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

export default class Recap extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (<Text>.fggdfgd</Text>).... its working fine on expo

Comment: close current packager and in the terminal type "cd android && ./gradlew clean" and then try to npx react-native start --reset-cache after that close terminal and then re-run the app

Comment: Either it could Gradle issue or packager

Comment: its ios on mac would i still do 'cd android?

Comment: yes I know  but you can check that after eject you should have two folders android and ios

Comment: @AnwarGul it didn't work man, i'm running mac on a vm its super slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change two files.

screens -> RécapitulatifScreen to RecapitulatifScreen

opne RdvScreen.js under screen folder and replace line number 5 with

import Recap from './RecapitulatifScreen';

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a  Packager issue

Brute force solution

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean --force&& npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```

or

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: the first command didn't work, watchman wasn't recognized. the second displayed this:

Comment: warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"